# Is there evidence that the culture of graffiti and tags and their motifs is not accepted in some ancient culture?

Tags: ancient-history, art

I have found some cases in google but I am interested in knowing what was the intention of it in the past times, since there were no mass media or materials to represent these expressions, currently it is relatively simple to make cultural murals in the case of my city Valparaiso Chile, this represents the culture and language of a people, politics, cultural movements etc.

Some articles that I have found are:

[Safaetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safaitic)

The Mayan graffiti apparently were socially accepted, but also because they were part of their culture, but is there evidence to the contrary?

[Maya graffiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Maya_graffiti)

I also found this interesting book that talks about the origins of graffiti in the Tikal Guatemala culture and its possible purposes.

[art-of-becoming-the-graffiti-of-tikal-guatemala](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/latin-american-antiquity/article/abs/art-of-becoming-the-graffiti-of-tikal-guatemala/91273A63E9FC971521C6A2E74F06D4C5)

Comment: What research have you done already? Google seems to have a number of available articles for "graffiti in the ancient world".

Comment: I have found some cases in google but I am interested in knowing what the intention of it was in the past times, I will edit the question a little better ...

Comment: Do "Romans" count as ancient?  Because there are tons of instances there.

Comment: I think there is ample literature on Roman graffiti - most of it was sexual, much of the rest was commercial/advertising, but there were still significant "Kilroy was here" style tagging.  There is at least one theory that the cave paintings are mere graffiti.  Artistic expression seems to be a human norm.

Comment: Rephrase my question thank you all very much,
Actually, more than looking for evidence of graffiti, I am interested in knowing the reasons for these acts in the event that they were not accepted to find their motives.

Comment: There are also examples of graffiti inside Egyptian pyramids, including such as "Built by chief architect Blork."

Comment: @GorttheRobot - Certainly worth clarifying with the poster (as you are doing), but according to our tag they do. And the poster used that tag.

Comment: @MCW - That theory is in fact what I was taught in my Music&Art History course back in the 80's. A lot of folks like to dignify it with the title "sympathetic magic", but the similarities with the way Roman and modern graffiti is carried out (eg: the need to keep retagging, and the retagging over old tags) seem to imply some similarity in impulse as well.

Comment: In ancient Rome (at least), not accepted by who? I think you'll find that 'acceptance' very much depended on where the graffiti was, what it said / depicted and who was 'judging' it.

Comment: I'm really not clear as to what you're asking here.  It would seem much easier to find the few examples of cultures where graffiti was accepted by society in general (rather that just by the subculture or individuals who did it)?